# Exporting a DB to XLS: It ignores formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2013

So I have a form that executes a VBA script via a macro. The purpose of said script is to open Excel, create a new workbook, gather information from several tables and export them to a formatted spreadsheet.  Each person has a sheet with their name, and the relevant data is printed in said sheet.  It works perfectly for the most part.  Only one problem... The table in Access where the name and demographics data is gathered from is formatted to sort by last name ascending alphabetically. The VBA script exports it in the order the names were entered.  I want my VBA script to respect the formatting in the database table, and I would prefer not to have to add an alphabetizing subroutine to my VBA script.

Table A Format:  ID, Active, Last, First, Role, Traveler, Resident, Preceptee, Phone, Completion

Table B Format: ID, Course, Course ID, Offered, HLC, Course Type

Last in Table A called "Roster" is the field with which I want my VBA script to sort alphabetically.  The database is already configured to do this.

Thanks in advance!

VBA Code:

```
Option Compare Database

' This module exports the database to a spreadsheet with specific formatting when called from a Macro
' Each Employee will have a sheet named thier last name which will contain all HLC modules they have completed in a list
' It is specific to this Database, but can be adapted to others.

' Version 1.0 Stable

Public Function ExportXLS(TblA As String, TblB As String, Optional names As String, Optional specific As Boolean)
'****************'
'Set up variables'
'****************'
Dim ctrA As Integer
Dim ctrB As Integer
Dim var As Long
Dim str As String

Dim excel As Object 'Pointer to Excel Application
Dim book As Object 'Pointer to Excel Workbook
Dim sheet As Object 'Pointer to Excell Sheet

Dim Roster As DAO.Recordset
Dim Course As DAO.Recordset
Dim Child As DAO.Recordset

Dim last_name As DAO.Recordset 'Matrix of pointers that will hold parts of the tables to be printed to the corresponding Excel sheets
Dim course_name As DAO.Recordset 'Matrix of pointers that will hold parts of the tables to be printed to the corresponding Excel sheets
'********************************************************'
'Initialize our tables into thier recordsets for analysis'
'********************************************************'
Set Roster = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(TblA)
Set Course = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(TblB)

str = "SELECT Last FROM Roster"
Set last_name = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(str)
str = "SELECT Course FROM [Course List]"
Set course_name = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(str)
'**************************************************************************'
'Create the new excel file with default parameters and print the cover page'
'**************************************************************************'
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set book = excel.Workbooks.Add
excel.Visible = True
Set sheet = book.Worksheets("Sheet1")
str = "Coversheet"
sheet.Name = str
sheet.Range("B2") = "HLC Database Export tool V1.0"
sheet.Range("B3") = "Written by Levi T Jackson, RN, BSN"
sheet.Range("B4") = "All rights reserved, Copyright 2021"
sheet.Range("B5") = "For use only by Emory Healhtcare, and others with permissions"
'**********************************'
'Main Loop, where the magic happens'
'**********************************'
ctrA = 0
Roster.MoveFirst
last_name.MoveFirst
Do Until last_name.EOF 'Move through the list of last names in the table Roster, one at a time
    
    If Roster!Active = True Then 'No need to report on inactive employees, use access query for that
        
        Set Child = Roster!Completion.Value 'Open a Recordset for the multivalued field Completion in Roster
        ctrB = 1
        If Child.EOF = True Then 'save the number of records for printing, or set to 0
            var = 0
        Else
            Child.MoveLast
            var = Child.RecordCount
            Child.MoveFirst
        End If
        Course.MoveLast
        
        If Child.EOF = False Then 'Avoid errors by not processing a page if no completion records exist
            
            Set sheet = book.sheets.Add(After:=book.Worksheets(book.Worksheets.count)) 'For active employees, make a new sheet and switch to it, and set its name to the current last name from Roster
            sheet.Activate
            sheet.Range("A1").SELECT
            str = Roster!Last & ", " & Roster!First
            sheet.Name = str
            sheet.Range("B2") = "Courses Completed"
            
            Do Until Child.EOF 'If there are records in Completion for the current name, print them, move on when done
                Course.MoveFirst
                course_name.MoveFirst
                Do Until Course.EOF
                    If Course![Course ID] = CInt(Child!Value.Value) Then
                        sheet.Range("D" & Mid(coordinates(ctrB), 2, Len(coordinates(ctrB)) - 1)) = Course![Course ID] 'prints course ID next to the name
                        sheet.Range("D2") = "'" & CStr(var) & " / " & CStr(Course.RecordCount) 'Prints number of records in completions
                        sheet.Range("B3") = "Course Name"
                        sheet.Range("D3") = "Course ID"
                        sheet.Range(coordinates(ctrB)) = Course!Course 'Prints course name
                        ctrB = ctrB + 1
                        Course.MoveLast
                        Course.MoveNext
                    Else
                        Course.MoveNext
                        course_name.MoveNext
                    End If
                Loop
                Child.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        
        ctrA = ctrA + 1 'I might use this later in code updates, counts how manmy records are processed
        Child.Close
        excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.SELECT 'Selects all of the cells
        excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Does the "autofit" for all columns
        sheet.Range("A1").SELECT 'Selects the first cell to unselect all cells
    End If
    Roster.MoveNext
    last_name.MoveNext
Loop
'Clean up recordsets
last_name.Close
course_name.Close
Roster.Close
Set Roster = Nothing
Course.Close
Set Course = Nothing
End Function

'Converts the iteration of the print course sub loop into a sheet coordinate cell and returns it as a string
'This function is here so that later a more complicated printing coordinate system can be easily added as the database grows larger

Private Function coordinates(num As Integer) As String
    coordinates = "B" & CStr(num + 4)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an **order by** clause to your OpenRecordset statements.

Comment: Looks like this would work, but it would require creating more recordsets for fields in Roster that I do work with. VBA will not let me open Roster with this argument which still opens in the order of the database, though it works fine on the individual fields opened FROM roster which are sorted.  Problem is BOTH need to be sorted.  Not as smooth as I wanted, but it seems like it would work.  Will experiment...

Comment: Alphabetization is very important in this case.  Looks like I will need to make an individual rst for each field in the table in order to have everything sorted. Pity, I can't always enter things into the db in alphabetical order.

Comment: str = "SELECT Last FROM Roster **Order By Last**"

Comment: That's exactly what I did, worked fine on the I individual records taken from roster. Only issue is that I need to rewrite a lot of code that still uses the Roster (since it isn't ordered) table to access other record sets. Just gonna take some time. Seems VBA will not let me open an entire table in this way.

Comment: I think you're right about rewriting the code but you don't need more recordsets, you already have five where I think two would suffice. I suggest you create a query object that joins the Roster and Course List tables, contains the fields you need, and sorts the way you want it, then in the VBA code, you can open a recordset over that query and just read it start to finish. You need the second recordset to read the multi-valued field.

Comment: This is what I did.  I simply made a query with only the fields form Rsoter that I needed in the correct order, and changed TblA to the name of the query when I opened the recordset. Done.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I hope you also fixed the typo the line sheet.Range("B5") = "For use only by Emory Healhtcare, and others with permissions"